# How to append dictionaries to a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to loop through a list of players getting their stats as a dictionary. But I do not manage to get the format right, it get's all messy.

What am I missing to do to get my desired output:

```
{ 
Player1: {stat1: 1, stat2: 2, etc,etc}
Player2: {stat1: 1, stat2: 2, etc,etc}
Player3: {stat1: 1, stat2: 2, etc,etc}
}

import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from pprint import pprint

player_name = ['Bernd Leno', 
 'Emiliano Martínez', 
 'Matt Macey', 
 'Héctor Bellerín']

for i in player_name:
    player_page = requests.get('https://www.premierleague.com/players/10483/{}/stats'.format(i))
    cont = soup(player_page.content, 'lxml')

    data = dict((k.contents[0].strip(), v.get_text(strip=True)) for k, v in zip(cont.select('.topStat span.stat, .normalStat span.stat'), cont.select('.topStat span.stat > span, .normalStat span.stat > span')))  
    player = {cont.select_one('.playerDetails .name').get_text(strip=True): data}

pprint(player)
```

Comment: The list, player_name, or are you referring to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare player  before the loop as:

```
player = {}
```

Then do the following in the loop:

```
player[playerName] = data
```

I have modified your code to strip off dependencies and demonstrated the solution you are looking for:

```
player_name = ['Bernd Leno', 'Emiliano Martnez', 'Matt Macey', 'Hctor Bellern']
player = {}
for i in player_name:
    #player_page = requests.get('https://www.premierleague.com/players/10483/{}/stats'.format(i))
    #cont = soup(player_page.content, 'lxml')
    data = {"stat1": 1, "stat2": 2}  
    player[i] = data

print(player)
```

And the output:

```
{'Hctor Bellern': {'stat2': 2, 'stat1': 1}, 
'Matt Macey': {'stat2': 2, 'stat1': 1}, 
'Bernd Leno': {'stat2': 2, 'stat1': 1}, 
'Emiliano Martnez': {'stat2': 2, 'stat1': 1}}
```

Comment: Thank you, missed that I should skip the last line and just refer player=data insted.

Comment: If you just do `player = data` then you will replace previous player's data and end up having only one player's data. Instead, you should do (as shown in the answer) : `player[playerName] = data`

Comment: Exactly, thnak you @fiveelements for the demonstation!

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is, that every player has different URL, so to scrape the statistics properly, it's necessary to find-out the players id:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from pprint import pprint

players_url = [
'https://www.premierleague.com/players/4985/Bernd-Leno/stats',
'https://www.premierleague.com/players/4245/Emiliano-Mart%C3%ADnez/stats',
'https://www.premierleague.com/players/10422/Matt-Macey/stats',
'https://www.premierleague.com/players/4474/H%C3%A9ctor-Beller%C3%ADn/stats']

# this is dict where we store all information:
players = {}

for url in players_url:
    player_page = requests.get(url)
    cont = soup(player_page.content, 'lxml')
    data = dict((k.contents[0].strip(), v.get_text(strip=True)) for k, v in zip(cont.select('.topStat span.stat, .normalStat span.stat'), cont.select('.topStat span.stat > span, .normalStat span.stat > span')))
    players[cont.select_one('.playerDetails .name').get_text(strip=True)] = data

pprint(players)
```

Prints:

```
{'Bernd Leno': {'Accurate long balls': '161',
                'Appearances': '34',
                'Assists': '0',
                'Catches': '7',
                'Clean sheets': '7',
                'Errors leading to goal': '5',
                'Fouls': '0',
                'Goal Kicks': '248',
                'Goals': '0',
                'Goals conceded': '43',
                'High Claims': '12',
                'Losses': '8',
                'Own goals': '0',
                'Passes': '971',
                'Passes per match': '28.56',
                'Penalties saved': '0',
                'Punches': '18',
                'Red cards': '0',
                'Saves': '110',
                'Sweeper clearances': '14',
                'Throw outs': '203',
                'Wins': '19',
                'Yellow cards': '0'},
 'Emiliano Martínez': {'Accurate long balls': '28',
                       'Appearances': '6',
                       'Assists': '0',
                       'Catches': '2',
                       'Clean sheets': '3',
                       'Errors leading to goal': '0',
                       'Fouls': '1',
                       'Goal Kicks': '39',
                       'Goals': '0',
                       'Goals conceded': '7',
                       'High Claims': '13',
                       'Losses': '3',
                       'Own goals': '0',
                       'Passes': '124',
                       'Passes per match': '20.67',
                       'Penalties saved': '0',
                       'Punches': '1',
                       'Red cards': '0',
                       'Saves': '9',
                       'Sweeper clearances': '2',
                       'Throw outs': '30',
                       'Wins': '3',
                       'Yellow cards': '0'},

...etc.
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, I solved the url problem by exracting all the player names to a list and than using .format(player_name), this because of the generic urls. The problem I encountered was that the dictionaty format was in-proper. Thank you for the provided solutions!

Comment: It would be a good idea to retain the player id as the names of players aren't necessarily unique.